# CREATE TABLE .... SELECT

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL.

I have a `SELECT` Statement that works fine.

However, when I try `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT...` statement using the same `SELECT` statement, I get an error.

```
CREATE TABLE db.daily_group_summary
SELECT 
    MAX(STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(t_stamp, '-', ','),'%Y,%m,%d %H:%i')) AS t_stamp
    (MAX(Total_filtrate_volume)) AS volume
FROM db.group_table
GROUP BY DAY(t_stamp)
ORDER BY t_stamp ASC;
```

With line 1 commented out, the `SELECT` produces the desired result.

With Line 1 included, I get error message:

> Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2018,11,26 14:52:36'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity – why `REPLACE` the dashes with commas, then parse format with commas? Why not just `STR_TO_DATE(t_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')`? Are the rows inconsistent, perhaps?

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html

Comment: no particular reason. I changed code as suggested, same error message

Comment: P.Salmon, I reviewed the specified page earlier. Is there something specific on that page I should look at?

Comment: Seems like the issue is with the data in the `t_stamp` column, that does not match your date spec : there are seconds in `'2018,11,26 14:52:36'`, not in `'%Y,%m,%d %H:%i'`.

Comment: Probably a typo (and not the primary problem) but you are missing a comma between the 2 values you wish to insert

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE db.daily_group_summary as (SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(t_stamp, '-', ','),'%Y,%m,%d %H:%i')) AS    t_stamp, (MAX(Total_filtrate_volume)) AS volume
FROM db.group_table
GROUP BY DAY(t_stamp)
ORDER BY t_stamp ASC);
```

Comment: Thanks P.Salmon. I would think it should work as it complies with  "13.1.17.5 CREATE TABLE ... SELECT Syntax" in the documentation. The curious thing is that the error message appears to relate to the SELECT part of the statement, specifically the time format, but as I stated previously, this SELECT statement works "stand-alone', so it would appear ok?

Comment: Thanks GMB. The time format does not cause an issue with the stand-alone SELECT statement. Not sure how this would impact the "CEATE TABLE … SELECT" structure. Any ideas?